# Get selected rows of a table with SWT.MULTI

Tags: java, swt

I have a Table table with SWT.MULTI. Now I want to get the selected rows.
Till now I had a single selection and got the selected row with a selection listener. But how do I get the selected rows of the SWT.Multi table?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`table.getSelection()` returns an array of `TableItems`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. But right after creating my question I found `table.getSelectionIndices()`which returns an int[]. That's exactly what I was looking for. Sorry I stole your time.

Comment: Don't worry!  If it was a steal of time, I wouldn't spend it answering. ;o)